# 500 Internal Server Error - Fresh Install

Tags: magento2, php, installation

I just setup a fresh install of cpanel.
Uploaded magento package - tested both.
Magento-CE-2.1.6-2017-03-29-12-40-05
Magento-CE-2.0.13-2017-02-20-06-04-35
tried php 56, 57,70
move .htacess
Verified I could get the html files.
Opened a ticket with cpanel for help.

Error Below.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@magento.************.com to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EqeK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EqeK.png) Me too "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Answer (score 3):

```
[Wed May 17 15:49:56.848543 2017] [core:alert] [pid 981] [client 208.74.121.106:23024] /home/aemadminuser/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 17 15:49:56.849866 2017] [core:alert] [pid 981] [client 208.74.121.106:23024] /home/aemadminuser/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 17 15:49:57.067999 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3839] [client 208.74.121.106:23074] /home/aemadminuser/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://magento.*********.com/index.php
[Wed May 17 15:49:57.069328 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3839] [client 208.74.121.106:23074] /home/aemadminuser/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://magento.*********.com/index.php
```

This appears to be due to the following line within your .htaccess:

```
[15:50:19 aem root@8483997 /home/aemadminuser/public_html]cPs# grep SetEnv /home/aemadminuser/public_html/.htaccess
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

This is due to **mod_env** not being installed on the server. You can install this Apache module via WHM by navigating to EasyApache 4 under the Apache Modules. If you would like I would be more than happy to assist with enabling this module however you will need to ensure that our IP addresses are able to successfully access WHM. I have included these IP addresses for you below:

> Couldn't access - bug with apacheeasy4

via the command line:

**Installing:**

```
ea-apache24-mod_env | x86_64
2.4.25-9.9.2.cpanel | EA4 27k
```

Upon completion I no longer received any errors within the Apache error_log however there was still an HTTP 500 error being generated by the Magento script. This contained the following error:

```
[17-May-2017 23:37:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No wrapper found supporting "UTF-8"' in /home/aemadminuser/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/StringUtils.php:135
```

With a bit of research, I was able to determine that this was due missing the **mbstring** PHP extension. I went ahead and installed this and now both the URLs are loading without any errors:

**Installing:**

```
ea-php56-php-mbstring | x86_64                     
5.6.30-12.12.1.cpanel | EA4 523 k
```

my site now loads.

Comment: Did you add the real webroot path and the real IP to your answer? oO

Answer (score 0):

The following command allowed me to locate the correct packages:

```
# yum list | egrep 'iconv|intl|zip' | grep 56
ea-php56-php-iconv.x86_64                     5.6.30-12.12.1.cpanel    EA4      
ea-php56-php-intl.x86_64                      5.6.30-12.12.1.cpanel    EA4      
ea-php56-php-zip.x86_64                       5.6.30-12.12.1.cpanel    EA4
```

You can use the following commands to install via command line:

```
# yum install ea-php56-php-iconv.x86_64
# yum install ea-php56-php-intl.x86_64
# yum install ea-php56-php-zip.x86_64
```